# NHibernate Mapping - 2 different columns in 2 logical tables in one mapping file and c# class

Tags: c#, nhibernate, mapping, multiple-columns

I have a problem for which I can't even find the right google keywords.

There are 2 databases. In the first one there is a table "Item" with 2 columns "DescriptionA", "DescriptionB". And in the 2nd database I have also a table called "Item" but with slightly different column names, let's say: "Description_A" and "Description_B".

My question is: Is it possible to create a hibernate mapping just in one mapping file and with one c#-class? For example a mapping that react like "If I can't find column DescriptionA then I will just read/write to column Description_A!"?

What I don't want to do is create 2 mapping and c# classes because that means 2 create 2 very similar c#-classes and mapping files and that can cause very large code redundancy.

What is the best aproach to solve such a problem?

Comment: I would also accept solutions that end up with one c# class and 2 or more hibernate mapping files. The aim is to avoid redundancy in c# code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution, built-in NHibernate, is the `ISessionFactory` configuration. We will **have to map all different entities twice**, but use only one mapping in the runtime - per connection string.

Because, as described above, we are talking about **2** DB. That means, that we would need **2** NHiberante `ISession` factories, which *(each of them)* will interact whit one of these DB - via different `connection strings`.

So, we will have for each application different config like documented here:

- [1.1. Getting started with NHibernate](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#quickstart-intro)

The first could look like this:

```
<hibernate-configuration xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2">
    <session-factory>
        <property name="connection.connection_string">Server=DB1...
        ...
        <mapping assembly="MyProject.Data" />
        <mapping assembly="MyProject.DataForDB1" />
    </session-factory>
```

While the second would have config like this

```
<hibernate-configuration xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2">
    <session-factory>
        <property name="connection.connection_string">Server=DB2...
        ...
        <mapping assembly="MyProject.Data" />
        <mapping assembly="MyProject.DataForDB2" />
    </session-factory>
```

The difference is not only the connection string... but also the information where are mapping files as **`Embedded Resources`** *(the MyProject.Data can contain those `.hbm.xml` files which are same for both schemas)*

That said, we would need two `Data` projects/libraries,

1. one with mapping for DB1 schema and
2. one with DB2 schema mapping

C# *Entities*, as well as any *Business logic*, will be shared. Even some *DAO* objects can be shared... just each DB interaction will use different mapping

**ESSENTIAL NOTE:** do not forget to mark any `.hbm.xml` file as **Embedded Resource** - each of them.